# Bit operations to count longest string of 1s in a binary number - connections to FFT?

Tags: number-theory, fourier-analysis, finite-fields, binary

I found this rather applied question on another forum. How to calculate size of largest string of consecutive 1s in a binary number. However the other forum had neither much of a focus on applied mathematics nor computational efficiency.

Two examples of this operation, the binary number with longest sub-string of ones colored $\color{red}{\text{red}}$:

$$0000110011001100{\color{red}{1111}}0110{\color{red}{1111}}0000  \to  4$$
$$000011001100110011010110{\color{red}{11111}}000  \to  5$$

---

I came up with a solution which was based on xor of bit-shifts: $\text{xor}(a<<1,a)$. This operation gives 1 at each position a run of 1 or 0 turns into a run of 0 or 1. Then we can mask by bit-wise and:ing with the number and it's bit-wise inverse to have the 1s mark "start" and "ends" of these runs.

$$\begin{array}{c}000111110000111100000\\001111100001111000000\end{array} \underset{xor}{\to}00100001000100010000$$
so the xor result marks the start and end of each run of ones, which is a start and which is an end we can get from and:ing with $a$ or $not(a)$. Then we can get run-lengths by subtracting the pairwise leftmost set bit positions in these two numbers, setting the bit to 0 and iterating. Turns out there exist hardware-implemented "find first set bit" operations in many CPUs nowadays.

---

Anyway, back to the mathematics. We can view the xor-operation above as a convolution with $[1,-1]$ on a vector of elements from the field $\mathbb{Z}_2$, which on a less discrete field would have been a very popular basic differential approximator. Now on same less-discrete fields it is common to do convolutions in the Fourier domain by using the convolution theorem. Is it possible to do something similar on the bit representation of a binary number? We can do elementwise multiplication and addition (bitwise and, xor) and integral ("population count"), but how can one do Fourier Transforms and similar stuff on these things, and do the computational properties carry over to finite fields?

Comment: How does that convolution help? Won't it just turn runs of 1s into a run of 0s? Why would IDing the longest run of 0s be any easier algorithmically? And if it is, then why convolution rather than bitwise negation?

Comment: The result of the xor will be 1s marking the position of start *or* end of each run and all interior 1s will turn 0 as you say. I expanded a bit in the question.

Comment: Ok. I think I understand how your method works. I was considering using look-up-tables listing maximum lengths of "left/internal/right" runs of ones within, say, a 16 bit mask, and then do similar scanning of the sequence. One word at the time. The usual caveats apply. You would need to be doing this a lot for building up such LUTs to pay dividends :-/

Comment: BTW sequence researchers have used discrete Fourier analysis in studying maximum run lengths. If you have good bounds on the magnitudes of DFT-components, then there is a method for getting bounds on something that might be called the density of 1s within a subsequence. We do get crude bounds on run lengths as a by-product, but you are interested in exact data, and I'm a bit skeptical about how useful DFT might be here. After all, flipping a single bit may make a noticeable difference in the maximum run length, but its effect gets drowned in the weighted averaging of DFT.

Comment: I also thought about look-up-tables for a bit then I found an even faster way to do it, but since I can't express it with some mathematics I can't really write a question about it.