# Measure of maximal support of a piecewise compactly supported function.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Say I have a continous positive real-valued function that is piecewise compactly supported (0 in between each "piece"). Is there some elegant or practical way to express it's largest support. I.e. the support of the largest "piece"? This is a poorly disguised calculus-version for continous functions of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1785530/bit-operations-to-count-longest-string-of-1s-in-a-binary-number-connections-to?lq=1).

---

**Own work** I am thinking something along the lines of a multiplication version of an integral

$$\prod_0^Tf(x)dx$$
That is: the infinitesimals are multiplied instead of summed. But I have little knowledge what would be required to be able to make such a concept rigorous and well defined. 
If we manage to define it and then define the **leaping short-term-productegral** function
$$g(t) = \prod_t^{t+T}f(x)dx$$
I suspect then that what I am searching for is the smallest possible $T \in \mathbb R^+$ so that $g(t) = 0, \forall t$.

Does this make sense to you or am I just rambling about?

---

**EDIT** Considering a definition of our pintegral by E.Girin in the comments: $$\prod_a^bf(x)dx = \exp\left[\int_{a}^b \log(f(x))dx\right]$$
This would make sense if we consider addition with $-\infty$ to have the following property: $a-\infty = -\infty$. I.e. log of 0 "short-circuits" the rest of the interval. It would just be undefined "diverging" using most calculus I have studied, but maybe we can skip that since we know there is an exp on the outside.

If we do a slight modification: replacing the with a mean value integral will give nicer smoother norms as the length of interval varies. Here is an animation of what happens with a discrete approximation as our candidate $T$ is increased continuously.

[image]

For reference, here is the length of each interval (left-to-right):
$$[\begin{array}{ccccccc}50&41&106&104&30&77&113\end{array}]$$

Comment: What is the domain of $f$? Also, I'm not really sure about what you're asking but, the closest thing I can think of a \emph{productegral} is $\exp(\int log|f(x)|dx)$

Comment: I also had the idea to have a log-like function, although it becomes $-\infty$ at 0. Domain is $\mathbb R$

Comment: You can try $\exp(\int\log f(x)+1dx)$, and look for the points were $f$ is equal to 1 instead.